# How do I make this shape of a card in CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: this shape]

How do I make this shape card in CSS? I want to create a card with rounded corners with a curve (halve circle) at the top of the card, connecting to the corners of the card.

Is this achieved by having two divs on top of eachother with one div having a halve circle and the other div as a card connecting to the div on top?

Is this achieved by having two divs on top of eachother with one div having a halve circle and the other div as a card connecting to the div on top?

Also, I have tried that, but the box-shadow will look odd as there are two divs.

[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should do the trick.

```css
.card {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 140px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 30px 30px / 60px 60px 30px 30px
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

You can read more about the [border-radius on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Comment: What, exactly, are you answering? The OP showed no work, just a requirement. There's no programming question here. Please don't post answers to questions that are just requirements.